# How to add options to mouse-right-click menu in Powershell forms

Tags: winforms, powershell, mouseevent, mouse, right-click

I have a basic `Powershell` form with a `textbox`. When I right-click on the `textbox`, a standard menu appears with copy, cut, paste etc...

My goal is to add a "clear log" option, that clears current `textbox` content. How can I add this option to right-click menu instead of doing/drawing an actual separate `button`?

Option will be enabled for this form only, I am not looking a general mouse-right-click solution from registry

Comment: To be able to show a ContextMenuStrip for a TextBox first you should set ShortcutsEnabled property of the TextBox to false, then assign a ContextMenuStrip to its ContextMenuStrip.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be able to show a `ContextMenuStrip` for a `TextBox` first you should set [`ShortcutsEnabled`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.shortcutsenabled(v=vs.110).aspx) property of the `TextBox` to `false`, then assign a `ContextMenuStrip` to its `ContextMenuStrip` property like this:

```
$form1= New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$textBox1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$contextMenuStrip1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ContextMenuStrip

$contextMenuStrip1.Items.Add("Item 1")
$contextMenuStrip1.Items.Add("Item 2")

$textBox1.ShortcutsEnabled = $false
$textBox1.ContextMenuStrip = $contextMenuStrip1

$form1.Text="Context Menu for TextBox"
$form1.Controls.Add($textBox1)

$form1.ShowDialog()
```

Comment: Thanks, works as expected. Now I just doing an event function for Item1/2, as clicks, right?

Comment: Btw, due line `$contextMenuStrip1.Items.Add` when running the script, in CMD I can see all item parameter. Do you know how to "silent" it?

Comment: assign it to a variable or use `| Out-Null` to suppress the output.

Comment: I love your answer here. I was trying to modify a little script using `ContextMenu` to use `ContexMenuStrip` to no avail, but now I can.

Answer (score 0):

add `[void]` the start of `$contextMenuStrip1.Items.Add`

like so:

```
[void]$contextMenuStrip1.Items.Add($item)
```